# xpst0003 xquery syntax error

Tags: xml, xquery, webharvest

I want to query a [webpage](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20%2a%20from%20google.translate%20where%20q=%22Now%20I%20can%20do%20anything%22%20and%20target=%22hi%22;&diagnostics=true&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys) through following x query code. please help me.
And it gives me following errors:
 XPST0003: XQuery syntax error in #...//json//sentences//trans); let#:
    expected "return", found ";".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config charset="UTF-8">
<var-def name="scrappedContent">
<xquery>
<xq-param name="doc">
    <html-to-xml outputtype="browser-compact" prunetags="yes">
      <http url="${url}"/>
    </html-to-xml>
  </xq-param>

  <xq-expression><![CDATA[
     declare variable $doc as node() external;
     let $transl := data($doc//query//results//json//sentences//trans);
     let $translitl := data($doc//query//results//json//sentences//translit);      

     let $data  := data($doc//div[@id="defId"])
     return
        <myContent>
          <transl>{$transl}</transl>
          <translitl>{$translitl}</translitl>
          <data>{$data}</data>
        </myContent>
   ]]>
</xq-expression>
</xquery>
</var-def>   
</config>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
 let $transl := data($doc//query//results//json//sentences//trans);
 let $translitl := data($doc//query//results//json//sentences//translit);
```

With:

```
 let $transl := data($doc//query//results//json//sentences//trans)
 let $translitl := data($doc//query//results//json//sentences//translit)
```

(No semi-colon after let's)

That should improve things..

HTH!